# Altering/wrapping php functions

Tags: php

Should i alter php functions?I'm making a forum from a scratch and i'm not sure should i alter any function.Some popular software alter some mysql functions and other functions,so i'm asking should i alter functions or leave them as it is.

Comment: What do you mean by "alter functions"?

Comment: You can't alter built in functions in PHP.

Comment: Do you mean 'override' functions?

Comment: @Rocket I think he means overriding a current functionality of a function. Something like overriding the order of explode's parameters whereas explode($array, $needle) instead of explode($needle, $array)

Comment: Well making a function that does for example mysql_query instead of the current one like
function db_query($query)
{
//some function code to execute query
}
Or edit/change the function in the source

Comment: What you're talking about is "wrapping". Not altering.

Comment: Down votes and close requests aren't appropriate here. Just a simple misunderstanding of the question. @YourCommonSense does a good job of giving a suitable answer.

Comment: @adlawson Yes,i'm sorry for misleading.I thought that alter is the right term,i guess i was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course, writing wrappers is always a good practice. Especially if you know what you're doing.
Strangely, but on this site of Stack overflow, no one to encourage such a practice. Everyone stuck with ready-made solutions like PDO and such. While every API cannot be used as is and **should** be wrapped into something usable.

Comment: Thank you,i thought that it could slow down performance